# I am trying to make a normal webpage responsive, page with images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've this webpage which I am trying to make responsive, I am a total beginner in RWD (media queries..etc) though I have an intermediate level knowledge of HTML & CSS. Here is the webpage in the zip-file.

https://ia902505.us.archive.org/5/items/MakeResponsive/MakeResponsive.zip

Can anyone help me explain how can I make it responsive, detailed and simple explanation would surely help a novice like me.

Regards.

Comment: try the Ink framework. its simple and intuitive. i absolutely love it and would recommend it over bootstrap all day. http://ink.sapo.pt

Comment: You can use CSS Media queries to make it responsive.

Comment: wonder how this question got up vote?

Comment: @ AppleBud, is there some simple tutorial on media-queries, which could help me get the job done?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai wasn't me :P

Comment: @LifeLongLearner please take the smart route and use a ui framework. save yourself the trouble of rolling your own responsive grid system.

Comment: @r3wt The page is already in "fixed" layout so does the framework help convert it into responsive layout?

Comment: @LifeLongLearner No. the framework gives you the tools to take your content and create a responsive layout from it. there is no magic conversion process, its all manual.

Comment: @r3wt Yeah, that's why I asked as Foundation and Bootstrap too don't help in such a scenario...

Comment: @LifeLongLearner it shouldn't be too hard. I converted several large projects from my own css to the Ink framework in just a few hours.

Comment: @r3wt The problem is that I'm new to RWD and don't really completely understand it. Plus I've no experience with media-query tags...etc Any tutorial which can help me get started as fast as possible?

Comment: @LifeLongLearner download ink @ https://github.com/sapo/Ink/releases/download/3.0.4/ink-3.0.4.zip http://ink.sapo.pt/cookbook/ contains examples. then read the reference manual for ui elements here http://ink.sapo.pt/ui-elements/ this should be enough to get you started. just apply yourself.

Comment: Please don't post download links. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @apaul34208

I didn't have a choice, my question demanded it...anyways will try to not to post further.

Comment: If your question demands it, your question is probably too broad for Stack Overflow. Consider narrowing your focus to making a specific element responsive rather than an entire site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few keys for me with responsive design:

Replace your fixed widths with percentages and max-widths.  This is probably the most important thing, along with understanding and utilizing media queries.  For example, if your main body width is 960px then your CSS

```
.Body { width: 960px }
.LeftSide { width: 640px }
```

becomes

```
.Body { width: 100%; max-width: 960px; }
.LeftSide { width: 66.667%; max-width: 640px; } /* width percentage is found by dividing 640/960 */
```

and so on and so forth. Once your screen hits a certain width, then you'll want to add a media query to make most/all elements 'block' and with a width of 95-100%.  So in the example above, you would ".LeftSide" to a media query for smaller screens:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
     .LeftSide{ width: 100%; display: block; }
}
```

Change display: inline to display: block on all elements eventually, to stack vertically for mobile devices.  When to do this depends on your page layout, but I've done it around 640px.  For example:

```
.items { display: inline; }

@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
     .items { display: block; }
}
```

On mobile the menu layout, headers and footers, etc. will all most likely display in vertical blocks.  I would look at a LOT of responsive sites and see what you like and don't like, and keep it simple to start.  I'm still new to it and enjoying getting a lot of practice with 'RWD'.

Also, watch your 95-100% widths if you also have padding.  I know that's probably basic CSS, but it caused me a few unnecessary headaches seeing that horizontal scroll bar on the bottom of my phone because of a few pixels of padding.

EDIT:  And don't forget the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

There are other options out there, some let you zoom and I don't believe this one does (on mobile).  But without this, on a mobile phone or tablet none of your media queries will work, as far as I know.

Good luck!

Comment: Why the down vote ? Oh yeah, and don't forget the viewport meta tag!

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, I cannot vote at all as I don't have 15 or more reputation points...I think someone else did it, someone even down-voted my question as if it was irrelevant or invalid. Instead of helping, some people are more interested in down-voting...

Comment: @ deebs, Can you explicate what should I include in the meta tag? I mean it would really help if you could tell me what to put into the content attribute and other attributes?

Comment: Thank you - I figured it was someone else.  It's a shame when people downvote honest answers that are just trying to help.  I'm still fairly new to it, but these 'beginner tips' definitely helped me.  I edited the answer with viewport info. And if this information helps or answers your initial question, can you accept it as the answer?

Comment: Though it does not completely answer my question yet it really helped a lot and cleared a lot of things, thank-you for your help.

Comment: My pleasure. Oh, and resizing your browser window is a great way to check how the layout changes for smaller screens. I do that all day long. In Chrome with inspect element you can see the screen width in pixels too, which was very helpful for me. Good luck!